# Rules compairing node with other nodes when created and fill in a field of both nodes depending on the values

Tags: 7, rules

I have been looking for more then a week to do this kind off stuff.

there is a content type with 3 kinds of fields
field A value can be a b c
field B value can be x y z
field C value can be 1 2 3

depending of someone creating a content of the same type and
he fills in the same values as someone else does.
That rules (or anything else) adds the value in a field D what was empty
a groep ID/name on both nodes.

the is just an example, but the project is way bigger and atm
im only struggeling with this kind off stuff and i really have
no idea.

thanks in advance
greets